# Canadian with expired conditional USA green card but I-797c letter. Can I apply for NEXUS (I-751)?

Tags: nexus

I am trying to apply for NEXUS. I have Canadian citizenship with a conditional US green card (through marriage to my American husband). My card is expired but I have my I-797c (for I-751) notice letter already. On the application it just states green card and nowhere to put this letter's information. My status is extended for a year as PR, but the card is obviously expired.

Can I still apply or do I have to wait for my 10-year green card to arrive? Do I need to go into the office to show them this? I am very confused, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why risk things? Just wait until you get your new card.

Comment: Because I go back every month twice from Seattle to vancouver , I asked my immigration attorney he said I qualify for it but on the application there is no where I can put the letter's information in. I was just wondering if anyone else was able to do it online. It might take over 1.5 years to get the new card. I would probably become USA citizenship before I get my 2nd green card interview under trump's administration processing time.

Comment: I believe all you need is your A# which remains constant between all your green cards. So just enter that. And given that citizenship processing is similarly backed up, it might be best to not count on that...

Comment: ah thanks!! forgot USCIS number was A number, yes my attorney told me citizenship is also backed but not nearly as bad as the green card in Seattle at least. He said I will probably apply for citizenship before I get the interview lol in seattle

Comment: in case anyone else is wondering, it worked and the nexus officer said the same thing about a # uscs number being tied. TY again

Comment: thanks for updating us, I adding my comment as an answer. If it's appropriate, please 'accept' it.

Answer (score 1):

All you need for your Nexus application is your A# which remains constant between all your green cards and is your USCIS number. So just enter that. For the expiration date, you can enter the extension date on your letter.